# Make an ImageView Visible with timer

Tags: android, imageview

I know that this question has been answered, but CountdownTimer doesn't work into my method.

So basically I have an animation for a button and a textview, after a button is clicked. But I want also to have an imageview, with a timer. Because imageview is a part of the textview that I want to show it to the user.
Any help?

**This is my code:**

**onCreate method:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);  
        leatseatbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.letseatbutton);  

        register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        signin1button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin1button);
        signinbutton_fb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signinbutton_fb);
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

**First onClickListener**

```
        leatseatbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

   @Override  
   public void onClick(View v) {    
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.width = 175;
       params.height = 40;
       params.setMargins(75, 240, 0, 0);
       leatseatbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
    edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100,0 );   
    slide.setDuration(1000);   
    slide.setFillAfter(true);   
    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    edittext.startAnimation(slide); 
   }  
  });
```

**Second onClickListener**

```
    signinbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

   @Override  
   public void onClick(View v) { 
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.width = 175;
       params.height = 40;
       params.setMargins(75, 240, 0, 0);
       signinbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
    edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100,0 );   
    slide.setDuration(1000);   
    slide.setFillAfter(true);   
    edittext.startAnimation(slide); 
   }  
  });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

```
    ....
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100,0 );

    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imageview.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    slide.setDuration(1000);   
    slide.setFillAfter(true);   
    edittext.startAnimation(slide); 
    ....
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get an error on the onCreate(MainActivity).

Comment: This code should be in `onClick(View)` method. What exactly error you got?

Comment: Yes it's inside onClick method.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at .com.example.mycode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)

Comment: Maybe you don't have any `ImageView` with id `@+id/imageView2` in your  layout?

Comment: No I have it in my layout

Comment: This means in other place you set `imageView2 = null` before animation ends.

Comment: I updated my code again. So I have and a second onClick method maybe that's why it didn't work. Because after I deleted the second onClick method it just worked right! Maybe you know a way so I can call two times the onClick method?

Comment: I don't see any way how your second `onClick` set `null`. If I were you I will clean and format code first. Sometimes that is enough to see mistake.

Comment: I found my mistake, I didn't registered it as a button up on my onCreate method. Thank you @neworld