# Using back button after onClick method in one activity

Tags: android, android-layout

So I am using an animation for buttons (my code is here :[Make an ImageView Visible with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018665/make-an-imageview-visible-with-timer/22019067))

What I am trying to do now is to make back button, after the onClick event, to go back to the original screen, when it's created (onCreate()). I have tried with finish() or onBackPressed() but it's only working if you have two different activities. So do you have any ideas?

Comment: In the onClick, set a boolean value, and onKeyUp check if its the back button and if boolean is the value you set it to.

Comment: Can you give me an example? with code if it's possible

Comment: See my answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean mHasHappened = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Other code

    yourElement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do your code
        mHasHappened = true;
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mHasHAppened) {
        //Do your back button press code
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourActivity.class));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No it doesn't work because in the time that motion ends the activity starts from the beginning without pressing back button.

Comment: I thought you wanted to restart your `Activity`. Be more specific or call the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: So I have an original screen then when a button is clicked (onClick method) an animation starts. When the user wants to go back to the original screen, he presses back button to go back and all that are in one same Activity and one same Layout. So my program is on the link above, if you want to take a look.